# No sound via HDMI

Tags: 14.04, sound, pulseaudio, alsa, hdmi

I have notebook and TV connected via HDMI cabel. But i have only video, but no audio.
Output of `aplay -l` looks like:

```
    **** List of PLAYBACK Hardware Devices ****
card 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 0: Generic Analog [Generic Analog]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 3: Generic Digital [Generic Digital]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
```

I tried `speaker-test -c 2 -r 48000 -D hw:0,3` but no effect.
`uname -r` output looks like:

```
4.4.0-36-generic
```

So tried to install 
`oem-audio-hda-daily-lts-xenial-dkms - 0.201609240546~ubuntu14.04.1` and reboot my computer, but it was no effect.

That my system

```
Linux eugene-pc 4.4.0-36-generic #55~14.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Fri Aug 12 11:49:30 UTC 2016 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

So I have a quetion - How can I solve that problem?

Comment: I've the same problem, solved going in settings --> audio and choose hdmi output.

Comment: i can choose HDMI output - but there's no effect - no sound on TV